# I am getting error in path_provider invokeMethod<String>("getApplicationDocumentsDirectory")

Tags: flutter, sqflite

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (23720): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'MethodChannel' has no instance method 'invokeMethod' with matching arguments.
E/flutter (23720): Receiver: Instance of 'MethodChannel'
E/flutter (23720): Tried calling: invokeMethod<String>("getApplicationDocumentsDirectory")
E/flutter (23720): Found: invokeMethod(String, [dynamic]) => Future<dynamic>
E/flutter (23720): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (23720): #1      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:65:22)
E/flutter (23720): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23720): #2      DatabaseHelper.initializeDb (package:snote/snote/utils/database_helper.dart:45:36)
E/flutter (23720): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because you are not using the latest version of Dart. I describe 2 solutions to get rid of this error.

**Solution 1:** use previous version of Path Provider 
i.e: **path_provider: 1.0.0**

**Solution 2:** if you want to use the latest version of path provider then update your flutter and Dart to the latest version.